# Como hacer para que las cantidades se sumen aparte de que los dígitos

Tags: python

Necesito que mi codigo vaya sumando las cantidades ingresadas, por ejemplo `123+12=135`. Ya tengo la suma de los dígitos de las cantidades, ejemplo `21` seria `2+1=3`, pero me falta lo de las cantidades. Mi código es este:

```
def sumas(numero):
    suma=0
    while numero!=0:
        digito=numero%10
        suma=suma+digito
        numero=numero//10
    return suma

print("-------------------------------")
num=int(input("Ingrese Número : "))
while num!=0:
print("Suma:",sumas(num))
print("---------------------------")
print("Total")
num=int(input("Ingrese Número: "))
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo único que te hace falta es una variable que vaya sumando todos los `num` que ingresas, esta variable podría llamarse `total` y en cada iteración del `while` sumar el valor actual de `total` mas el valor ingresado de `num`

Es decir:

```
total = total + num
```

Si utilizamos el operador de asignación `+=` podemos acortarlo de la siguiente forma

```
total += num
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
def sumas(numero):
    suma=0
    while numero!=0:
        digito=numero%10
        suma=suma+digito
        numero=numero//10
    return suma

print("-------------------------------")
num=int(input("Ingrese Número : "))
total = 0
while num!=0:
    print("Suma:",sumas(num))
    print("---------------------------")
    total += num
    print("Total:", total)
    num=int(input("Ingrese Número: "))
```